# Есть ли аналог append в Twig?

Tags: javascript, html, twig

```
{% block page %}
    <ul class="gallery">
      {% set foo = 0 %}
      {% for products in prodArr %}
        {% if foo % 4 == 0 %}
          <ul class="slides">
              <li>Product</li>
          </ul>
        {% else %}
          <li>Another Product<li> // вот тут 
        {% endif %}
        {% set foo = foo + 1 %}
     {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: А кто вам мешает вытащить `ul` из условия `if`?

Comment: @StackOverflow Я хочу что б каждые 4 итерации, создавалось новый ul вместе с  li

Answer (score 0):

Нет, такого аналога нет. Вам стоит попробовать построить условие немного по-другому, или подготовить массив для отображения заранее, разбив его на части, к примеру функцией array_chunk